# Is there a way to only authorise logged user to see my whole WordPress site without plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

is there a way to only authorise logged user to see my whole WordPress site without plugin?

My goal is to see the login page if your are not logged-in or registered.

I found that on another post:

```
<?php if(!is_user_logged_in()){wp_redirect( 'http://www.your-blog.com/wp-login' ); exit;}?>
```

Whit this solution I have to put on top from all my pages. Is there a way to put just some line of code in the functions.php to get the same results?

Comment: I think you should use this code only in header.php , no need to put in all pages. it will by default call in all pages if you put in header.

Comment: @HelpingHands , this kind of logic should go in *functions.php*

Answer (score 0):

Put below code into your current theme's functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'muplugins_loaded', 'my_plugin_override' );

function my_plugin_override() {
    if(!is_user_logged_in()){
       wp_redirect( 'http://www.your-blog.com/wp-login' ); 
       exit;
    }
}
```

muplugins_loaded is the earliest action hook.

For more dfetails check - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162862/how-to-get-wordpress-hook-run-sequence

Comment: Just use `wp_redirect(wp_login_url())` instead of hard-coding the site path.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.
I tried this piece of code:
`add_action( 'muplugins_loaded', 'my_plugin_override' );

function my_plugin_override() {
    if(!is_user_logged_in()){
        wp_redirect(wp_login_url());
       exit;
    }
 }`
But the site is still visible and is not redirecting to my login page.

Any idea why?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: In the top of my functions.php

Comment: @Dan, try to put it at the end of your functions.php

Comment: Do I have to make a mu-plugins folder in my wp-contents and create a plugin with a functions file and put that inside?

Comment: nope, you should put it at the end of your current activated theme's functions.php file.

Comment: @Milap - Not working at the end of my functions.php from my theme…

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the end of my functions.php doesn't do the trick:

```
add_action( 'muplugins_loaded', 'my_plugin_override' );

function my_plugin_override() {
    if(!is_user_logged_in()){
       wp_redirect( wp_login_url() ); 
       exit;
    }
}
```

Don't know why, any Idea? 
I have found a plugin who made the trick, but I want to try to understand how to get it work without plugin with a simple solution.

Thank you